# How to edit ArcGIS Server .json?

Tags: arcgis-server, json

Is it possible to edit the .json format, which is created by default when publishing a service on ArcGIS for Server?

For a project we have the following problem:

- Our by default created .json for a Feature Service Layer looks e.g. like **[this](http://pastebin.com/5pfV4kWZ)**.
- We want to change some of these .json elements like edit the objectID name or adding another element like "api_key"?

Because there is also another group, which works simultaneously on another application, both teams should use the same data coming from an ArcGIS Server.

So....is there a way to edit the json schema?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python and the json module:

```
import json
json_data=open('arcgis.json') # your file has an error in line 36: "imageData": "blablabla",
data =json.loads(json_data)
# the result is a Python dictionary
print data.keys()
[u'drawingInfo', u'typeIdField', u'supportsRollbackOnFailureParameter', u'globalIdField', u'supportsAdvancedQueries', u'id', u'relationships', u'capabilities', u'currentVersion', u'geometryType', u'ownershipBasedAccessControlForFeatures', u'type', u'useStandardizedQueries', u'supportedQueryFormats', u'isDataVersioned', u'syncCanReturnChanges', u'allowGeometryUpdates', u'description', u'defaultVisibility', u'extent', u'objectIdField', u'htmlPopupType', u'types', u'hasM', u'displayField', u'name', u'templates', u'supportsStatistics', u'hasAttachments', u'fields', u'maxScale', u'copyrightText', u'hasZ', u'maxRecordCount', u'minScale', u'editFieldsInfo']
# you can read the values
print data['name']
u'Wastebin'
print data['extent']
{u'xmin': 845515.69519999996, u'ymin': -1860754.5734999999, u'ymax': 6795261.5813999996, u'xmax': 3884733.2325000018, u'spatialReference': {u'wkid': 102100, u'latestWkid': 3857}}
print data['extent']['xmin']
845515.69519999996
print data['extent']['spatialReference']['latestWkid']
3857
# you can change the values
data['name'] = "new"
print data['name']
u'new'
# or add new key/value
data["api_key"]= 1234
print data["api_key"]
1234
# and save the new file
with open('new.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have any link with further details? Because I do not really know, how to apply this script.  Another question: So...modifying the json schema by using the Python script would modify the json, which is used by the corresponding ArcGIS Server Service?